# Nhibernate: Mapping a conditional many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following object model:

```
public class Organizer
{
    private int id;

    public virtual int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string fullName = "";

    public virtual string FullName
    {
        get { return fullName; }
        set { fullName = value; }
    }

    private List<Email> emails = new List<Email>();

    public virtual List<Email> Emails
    {
        get { return emails; }
        set { emails = value; }
    }
}


public enum EmailType
{
    Primary, Secondary
}

public class Email
{
    private int iD;

    public virtual int ID
    {
        get { return iD; }
        set { iD = value; }
    }
    private string emailAddress = "";

    public virtual string EmailAddress
    {
        get { return emailAddress; }
        set { emailAddress = value; }
    }
    private EmailType emailType = EmailType.Primary;

    public virtual EmailType EmailType
    {
        get { return emailType; }
        set { emailType = value; }
    }

    private List<Organizer> organizers;

    public virtual List<Organizer> Organizers
    {
        get { return organizers; }
        set { organizers = value; }
    }
}
```

And I have the following database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmailAddresses](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](550) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Organizers](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](550) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Organizers_PrimaryKeys](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PrimaryKeyID] [int] NULL,
    [PrimaryKeyTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [OrganizerID] [int] NULL
)
```

Now, I'm having serious issues figuring out how to map this with nhibernate (not fluent nhibernate). Basically, I want it mapped such that when I do "session.Save(anOrganizer)", data is sometimes written to two tables, and sometimes written to three. For example, say we have OrganizerA, and he has three emails: email_1, email_2, and email_3. email_1 has EmailType.Primary, while the other two have EmailType.Secondary. So when we save OrganizerA, the following happens:

1. OrganizerA's details get written to table Organizers
2. email_1, email_2, and email_3 all get written to the EmailAddresses table (if they don't already exist there)
3. And a new row is created in the Organizers_PrimaryKeys table, where email_1's id is written as PrimaryKeyID, and OrganizerA's id is written as OrganizerID (don't worry about PrimaryKeyTypeID. I'll figure that out later).

So how the heck do I map this kind of relationship?  So far I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="BLL"
                   namespace="BusinessLogic">

  <class name="Organizer" table="Organizers">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="FullName">
      <column name="FullName"/>
    </property>
    <bag name="Emails" table="Organizers_PrimaryKeys" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="true" >
      <key column="Id"/>
      <many-to-many class="Email" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="BLL"
                   namespace="BusinessLogic">

  <class name="Email" table="EmailAddresses">
    <id name="ID">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="EmailAddress" unique="true" type="string" >
      <column name="EmailAddress"/>
    </property>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have no idea what to put in the Email.hbm.xml to complete this "conditional" many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate between primary and secondary Email to two different object because they are not the same kind of entities. Add Organizer class a one-to-one relation to PrimaryEmail and keep the current many-to-many SecondaryEmail list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="BLL"
               namespace="BusinessLogic">

   <class name="Organizer" table="Organizers">
   <id name="Id">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="native" />
   </id>
   <property name="FullName">
      <column name="FullName"/>
   </property>
   <one-to-one name="PrimaryEmail" class="PrimaryEmail" />
   <bag name="Emails" table="EmailAddresses" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="true" >
     <key column="Id"/>
     <many-to-many class="SecondaryEmail" />
   </bag>
  </class>

  <class name="PrimaryEmail" table="Organizers_PrimaryKeys">
    <id name="ID">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="EmailAddress" unique="true" type="string" >
      <column name="EmailAddress"/>
    </property>
  </class>

  <class name="SecondaryEmail" table="EmailAddresses">
    <id name="ID">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="EmailAddress" unique="true" type="string" >
      <column name="EmailAddress"/>
    </property>
  </class>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

You definitely got me on the right track. It's sometimes really hard for me to think differently about my domain model, in a way that is more ORM-friendly. 

In the end, given that the primaryEmail is in a one-to-one relationship with the organizer, I simply added it as a column to the Organizers table in the db, and changed the Organizer.hbm.xml accordingly. I copied your SecondaryEmail suggestion exactly. And now it works perfectly. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

email_1, email_2, and email_3 append to Organizers table as properties

Comment: Seriously?  That's the answer?  I would think that flies in the face of a normalized database schema.

Comment: du-sijun: This is a hack, not an answer.